# What is the best way to add new data to BigQuery through BigQuery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Django as my backend framework to connect my web app with BigQuery. How I would do it is to use BigQuery API in `views.py` to fetch data from BQ. So far from my research, I found 2 ways I can add data to BQ from my Django:

1. Using the `insert_rows_json()` method where I would just need to have the data in a JSON format and it would append the data to the BQ.
2. Using the `to_gbq()` method where I would need the data to be in a Pandas DataFrame and I could include the parameter `if_exists="replace"` to update existing tables on the BQ.

Currently, for adding new data, I would use **method 1** and for other operations such as updating and deleting, I would use **method 2**.

My question: Is it better if I use **method 2** for all of my operations, or should I just stick to using **method 1** for adding new data and **method 2** for other operations?

**OR PERHAPS** is there any other way that is more efficient for the web app to run even faster?

Comment: Insert is a good method to have the data available fast; for the next query the data is already present. However, streaming inserts is priced high with $0.010 per 200 MB. On the other hand is batch loading free of charge and I would recommend this for transfering data from other sources.


https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery   and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: Hello. Before answering your questions, I would like to know why you want BigQuery for use cases? How frequently do you want to perform update or delete operations on BigQuery? Because, your questions seems like you are going to use BigQuery as your transactional database for your application. But, BigQuery is a data warehouse designed for analytics. It's not intended as a transactional relational database.

Comment: @VishalK I'm using BigQuery because the client wants to store its data inside of BigQuery, so I'm providing a web app for them to input their data into BQ and fetch data so I could display them in table and graphs for the client. They use BQ to do analytic and machine learning work. Update and delete operations shouldn't be used that often (only when there is a mistake in input), so most operations done are just inserting data (with hoping there's little to no mistake, which I should be able to tackle with a good UI design).

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for the references. Will give it a read!

Comment: Hi @Owenn, If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery):

> For new projects, we recommend using the BigQuery Storage Write API instead of the tabledata.insertAll method. The Storage Write API has lower pricing and more robust features, including exactly-once delivery semantics. The tabledata.insertAll method is still fully supported.

- You can try [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) instead of the legacy insert_rows_json() method for streaming data into BigQuery. It has lower pricing and more robust features, including exactly-once delivery semantics. If you still need to use the legacy streaming insert_rows_json() method, you can use it. It is still fully supported by Google Cloud.
- Use the insert_rows_json() method for streaming data into BigQuery because that is a recommended method and maintained by Google Cloud.
- You can also UPDATE and DELETE table data using DML queries via [BigQuery client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data#updating_data). But, there are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations) in BigQuery when doing UPDATE and DELETE queries immediately after streaming inserts.

> Rows that were written to a table recently by using streaming (the tabledata.insertall method or the Storage Write API) cannot be modified with UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statements. The recent writes are those that occur within the last 30 minutes. All other rows in the table remain modifiable by using UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statements. The streamed data can take up to 90 minutes to become available for copy operations.

- If you still want to use the to_gbq() method for updating and deleting the table, you can use it. Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) you can find the difference between the `pandas-gbq` and `google-cloud-bigquery` libraries.